# Entity Framework 6 Table-per-Type inheritance mapping leaving discriminator value (Undefined) for type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a project where I am attempting to use table per type inheritance, source code [here](https://github.com/NotMyself/AccountingModel).

I start with an abstract base class of [Transaction](https://github.com/NotMyself/AccountingModel/blob/master/src/AccountingModel/Model/Transaction.cs#L7). There are several sub classes of transactions, Expense, Deposit, Release and Encumberance. The generated migrations are what I expect; a Transactions table with a Discriminator column.

Everything seems to be working as expected, until I try to store an [Encumberance](https://github.com/NotMyself/AccountingModel/blob/master/src/AccountingModel/Model/Transaction.cs#L39) to the database. It stories it as expected with the transaction values in the transaction table and the other values in the encumberances table. But the Discriminator value in the Transactions table is (Undefined).

I cannot figure out how to set this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of research, I have discovered this was a misunderstanding on my part. With Entity Framework 6, there are 3 methods of persisting a an inheritance chain to the database.

- **Table per Hierarchy (TPH)** - All data is stored in a single table, types are differentiated by a discriminator column. A single query can be used to get all types.
- **Table per Type (TPT)** - Data is stored in two or more tables, where the common attributes of the base class are in a master table. Queries are joined to the tables and then union-ed to differentiate types. No discriminator column needed.
- **Table per Concrete Class (TPC)** - All data is stored in separate tables for each class. No joins are needed for queries, but multiple queries are still needed.

In my scenario, I had a hybrid of TPH and TPT, which worked perfectly well. Although any DBA who looked at the schema it generated might want to punch me in the face. So, in the end I ended up going with TPH for now, until my transactions become different enough to justify moving all of them to TPT.